# 400 Bad Request using postman copied request code

Tags: java, http-post, postman, httprequest, okhttp

I have taken the request code from

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
String json = String.format("{'sex': %s,'age': %d,'evidence': []}", gender, age);
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("https://api.infermedica.com/covid19/diagnosis")
        .post(body)
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
        .addHeader("App-Id", "XXXXXX")
        .addHeader("App-Key", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
        .addHeader("User-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.19.0")
        .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        .addHeader("Postman-Token", "58fbac21-182b-41e0-bceb-0905d0605858,cd9580e6-f262-4440-ba33-b85877dd087c")
        .addHeader("Host", "api.infermedica.com")
        .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
        .addHeader("Content-Length", "56")
        .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")
        .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
        .build();

com.squareup.okhttp.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I am attempting to make a post request. I have successfully run the request in postman. And I have copied the code from postman. But when I run the request in java I get a 400 Bad Request. And I dont know why because all of the headers and the body is exactly the same as in postman.

Comment: Have you try to use not all the headers from postman? I think "Postman-Token", "User-Agent" is not needed. May be you just need the "App-Id" and "App-Key".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing quotes for Sex in your input

Confirmed here https://developer.infermedica.com/docs/covid-19

```
curl "https://api.infermedica.com/covid19/diagnosis" \
  -X "POST" \
  -H "App-Id: XXXXXXXX" -H "App-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "sex": "male",
    "age": 30,
    "evidence": []
}'
```